# JUnit AssertTrue doesn't fail the test

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber, assert

Our system can run over both web platform and Windows platform. We created tests for the web platform by `Cucumer`, `Selenium`, and `JUnit` and it works fine but very slow.

We decided to execute the same tests on the Windows platform, and created a program which integrates with it, operated by the `JUnit`. It works very very faster, but we have a problem.

Most cases when `AssertTrue` has to fail the test, it actually calls `fail()`, but the test continues running to the next sentence. Moreover, the output of the `fail()` is actually printed.

Why does it occur?

**EDIT:** I don't know what can be clearer than what I wrote, but you want:

```
assertTrue("retval = " + params[0], params[0].equals("0"));
```

When `params[0] = "1018"` the test is supposed to stop with failure. But it continues to the next code instruction.

The output is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: retval = 1026
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
    at com.eshbel_17_0.WinformBridge.readToJava(WinformBridge.java:225)
    at com.eshbel_17_0.WinformExec.runDirectProcedure(WinformExec.java:111)
    at com.eshbel_17_0.Definitions.the_user_runs_the_direct_activation(Definitions.java:362)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:13)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:30)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:35)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:298)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:48)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:91)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:89)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:40)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: showing code might make it a bit more clear. fail() can be anything, do you have a method of your own, you are calling there?

Comment: @JiriTousek provided

Comment: You are testing on retval, but retval is nowhere in your assert. I don't get it

Comment: @Stultuske you right. not `retval` but `params[0]`.
When `params[0] == "1018"` the `AssertTrue` calls `fail()` but the test continues to the next instruction.

Comment: @Aharon No, you actually didn't provide it, as evidenced by the fact that nowhere in the question we can see any `catch(Throwable ...)` block that actually caused your problem as per your answer. So it was impossible for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I found why it happens, and it's so foolish mistake!

This code is sorrounded by `try-catch` block, and gets also `Throwable e`. it includes also `Assertion Error` exception, so test not failed.